# Angular + Electron base app does not refresh a section of the page

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, electron

I am working on an Angular 9 + Electron app that reads files names (not the content) from the File System and presents them on a panel in a tree-like structure. I have the Angular portion working just fine on the browser, but when I try to run it within the Electron context, the panel does not show the tree-structure. The only way to make it show it, is to resize the Electron-app window or force an event (click on a button). The question that I have is how do I make it render the tree-structure once the data arrives?

The data coming from the Electron process shows up on the console when I add a console.log for the Electron service within Angular and Angular gets it and processes the data. But the console stops printing when the data has to be transferred from the app.component.ts file to its child component. The console stop with the following warning:

"Security Warning: webFrame.executeJavaScript was called without worldSafeExecuteJavaScript enabled. This is considered unsafe. worldSafeExecuteJavaScript will be enabled by default in Electron 12."

And stops printing anything else.

Here is the code that I am using:

In `index.html`

```
...
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self'">
...
```

In app.ts (Electron main file):

```
...
function createWindow() {
  
  win = new BrowserWindow(
    { 
      "width": 800, "height": 600,
      "title": "My Life Notes...",
      "icon": path.join(__dirname,`./favicon.ico`),
      webPreferences: {
        "nodeIntegration": true,
        "worldSafeExecuteJavaScript": true
      } 
    }
  );

  win.loadURL(
    url.format({
      "pathname": path.join(__dirname, `./index.html`),
      "protocol": "file:",
      "slashes": true
    })
  );

  win.webContents.openDevTools();

  win.on("closed", () => {
    win = null;
  });
}
...
```

In app.component.ts:

```
...
NOTES_DATA: NotesNodeImp[]=[];

  constructor(private electron_service: ElectronServiceFile,
              private select_service: SelectedNodeService){
    this.electron_service.loadFiles();
    
  }
...
  ngOnInit(){
    this.electron_service.notes.subscribe( notes =>{
      console.log("app.component notes ", notes);
      notes.forEach( note => {
        let name_parts = note.split('-'); 
        let notesObj =new NotesNodeImp(Number.parseInt(name_parts[0]));
        notesObj.name = note;
        notesObj.label = name_parts[1];
        this.NOTES_DATA.push(notesObj);
      });
      this.NOTES_DATA = Object.assign([], this.NOTES_DATA);
    })
...
```

In app.component.html

```
<div class="app-nav">
  <app-navigation [data_saved]="NOTES_DATA"></app-navigation>
</div>
```

In electron.service.ts:

```
...  
constructor() {
    if ((<any>window).require) {
      try {
        this.ipc = (<any>window).require('electron').ipcRenderer;
      } catch (e) {
        throw e;
      }
    } else {
      console.warn('App not running inside Electron!');
    }

    this.ipc.on('getNotesResponse', (event, notes) => {
      this.notes.next(notes);
      console.log("available notes ", notes);
    });
    
  }

  loadFiles(){
    console.log('load files: ');
    this.ipc.send('loadNotes');
  }
...
```

In navigation.component.ts (child)

```
  ...
  data: NotesNodeImp[]=[];

  @Input('data_saved') 
  set data_saved (d: NotesNodeImp[]){
    console.log("data1 " , d)
    this.data = d;
  }
  ...
```

Here is the console:

[The console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYKcU.png)

The image shows that the loadFiles method gets called first, then app.component.ts sends an empty array to its child (navigation.component.ts). However, when the data does arrived from the Electron ipcMain process, app.component.ts receives it, processes it and it doesn't seem like it sends it to its child component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the browser engine is not sending a change event when the data arrives to the component. Angular has several ways to deal with this. I chose
this.zone.run(() => this.NOTES_DATA );
Which to send the data to the components that need to know. For an explanation on how to use zones: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/01/zones-in-angular-2.html